# If my PCs are in a tunnel of water and it magically freezes, will this have violent effects?

Tags: magic, godbound

Currently, my PCs are semi-trapped underground in a narrow, but tall (20ft) vertical tunnel surrounded by rock (with the ceiling being about 5ft thick, the rest being much thicker). The tunnel is filled with cold water, and the enemy they're trapped with is planning to freeze it solid (over about one round), making it expand suddenly and violently.

What kind of effects is this likely to have? From some cursory research, I imagine it should deal some decent damage to the players and the structure, mainly focused on the top of the cylinder?

The system is Godbound, and the tunnel is entirely filled with water. All of the characters are capable of breathing the water.

Comment: Is this *actually* a role-playing games question? That is, do you expect that the game's rules *can* somehow cover this if extrapolated correctly by an expert? If not, and you instead want a realistic answer, you need a different stack (maybe Physics.SE?) so as to get answers from a hydrologist or whoever.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I mean, I've never heard of Godbound, so I don't know what the rules cover. However, it certainly seems like they're asking for a reasonable interpretation of the rules of that system.

Comment: @goodguy5 I'd also not heard of it before and am likewise totally unsure if the game has a physics engine robust enough to determine the effects on PCs and *the surrounding construction* of flash-freezing a tunnel full of water. (Seriously, if the game *does*, that's badass, rivaling *Aftermath!* and *Phoenix Command* in its detail, and I'ma gonna look into *Godbound*!) My point was, really, that [the site frowns on hard-science questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3418/8610) and, if the asker wants realism that the game doesn't support, asking elsewhere is better.

Comment: *Godbound* is a game built on the 1980s' Basic D&D engine to play infant/demi-gods. It's by the same designer who adapted BD&D into *Stars Without Number* for playing *Traveller*-like campaigns.

Answer (score 10):

Page 27, "Hurt Several Targets". If it's Word-powered magic, and it seems like it should hurt somebody, and it hurts several somebodies, you use those guidelines.

To quote the aforementioned section on page 27:

> When blasting a group of targets in sight, a miracle can inflict a 1d6 die of damage per two levels or hit dice of the character, with a 10d6 cap. This can usually catch a single group of enemies within sight range, but if there are allies mixed up and the Godbound wants to spare them this wrath, then the targets get an appropriate saving throw to resist the damage. As with hurting a single target, such a blast counts as a Smite action.

Comment: Welcome to the Role-Playing Games StackExchange @KevinCrawford! We just ask that you provide a bit more clarity (maybe use some quotes from the rulebook) when giving answers.

Comment: Should the same damage be dealt to the surrounding environment?

Answer (score 1):

Godbound doesn't generally do expansive modelling of physics. That said, there are a few ways to handle this.

Make it a zone of danger. (p27 Godbound) if their enemy is a word bound foe with access to miracles.

> Create a Wall or Zone of Danger
>   Miracles to create a wall of fire, seal a victim in a stone block, or
>   otherwise create a hazardous zone take one round to form. If victims
>   in range move out of the zone that round, they take no damage. Otherwise, damage is usually one point per level per round in the zone.

From p 145, see how much damage they take.

> Use half the creature’s
>   hit dice for level-dependent eﬀects of the gift, rounded up, up to a
>   maximum of 10 for gifts used by creatures of 20 hit dice or more

You could also use some sort of smite, as mentioned above, doing 1d6 damage per two levels, or a normal corona of fury, for 1d8 damage per two levels for everyone within 30 feet.

If you want to add some interesting effects, see p169 for a list of impairments. For example.

> Stun. Victim must make an appropriate
>   saving throw to take any action on a
>   round

Perhaps PCs could be forced to make a hardiness save to move and attack?

In terms of how tough a typical wall should be there is no guidance from Godbound, but SWN, another system he designed, has an answer from p42.

> Instapanel: In its compressed form, an instapanel is a two-kilo
>   cube of ceraplast fve centimeters on a side. When a Type A power
>   cell is inserted in the cube’s side, it immediately expands to an
>   opaque, waterproof ceraplast sheet 2 meters on each side and a
>   centimeter thick. Five minutes later the ceraplast hardens into a
>   tough, rigid shape, but until then it can be folded or bent by hand.
>   Instapanels can be bonded to one another with a metatool or a
>   postech toolkit. Breaking an instapanel requires inﬂicting at least
>   twelve points of damage on it

Or alternatively, from hard light, p29, a super tough alien wall.

> The tower walls are as durable as
>   hull plating, and have Armor 10 against non-Gunnery weapons.
>   It takes 20 points of damage to knock a human-sized hole in a
>   wall.

Godbound uses a conversion system of one Godbound hitpoint or hitdice to one SWN or D&D hitdice, not hitpoint. So a, level 4 fighter might have 4HD in Godbound. As such, if we divide 12 by 4.5, the average of a 1d8 hit dice, that suggests in godbound an instapanel would have around 2-3 HD, while a very tough wall might have 4-5 HD and have immunity to non magical weapons like swords. Unless your walls are notably tougher than an advanced futuristic wall material, they will probably break upon being hit with a smash of divine energy as such, which may do 5-10 damage. This is simply a rough estimate but generally walls don't do well around heavy weaponry.

To summarize-

Use a zone of danger, a smite, or an impairing condition, or some combination of the above. Unless the walls are made of a very powerful and advanced material, beyond futuristic alien alloys, they will probably break.